# Returning a parent function inside $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have a service that checks if a serial exists in my DB.
I want the service to return the barcode of the serial if it exists, or "false" if it doesn't.

My code doesn't seem to work, since I'm in an inner function.
I have tried calling another function upon response but then it won't affect my scope.

Here's my code:

```
  $scope.checkSerial = function(e) {
    if (e.which==9) {
      res = serialChecker.check($scope.itemsData, $scope.serial, e);
    }
  }    

.service('serialChecker', function($log, $http) {
 this.check = function(_itemsData, _serial, e) {
   isok = false;
     // Fetch serial barcode
     config = {
       params: { serial: _serial, action: 'check_serial' }
     };
     $http.get("srvr.php", config)
     .then(function(bcresponse) {
       $log.info("Currently looking at serial: " + _serial);
       barcode = bcresponse.data.barcode;
       if (barcode==false) {
         return false;
       }
       angular.forEach(_itemsData, function(value, key){
           angular.forEach(value.Items, function(value, key) {
             if (value.Codebars == barcode) {
               return barcode;
             }
           });
        });
     });
 }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get` is an async function and it returns the promise, not the result of the call. To use the result add `then` function to `serialChecker.check` promise chain:

```
.service('serialChecker', function($log, $http) {
  this.check = function(_itemsData, _serial, e) {
    // Fetch serial barcode
    config = {
      params: { serial: _serial, action: 'check_serial' }
    };
    return $http
      .get("srvr.php", config)
      .then(function(bcresponse) {
        $log.info("Currently looking at serial: " + _serial);
        barcode = bcresponse.data.barcode;
        if (barcode==false) {
          return false;
        }
        angular.forEach(_itemsData, function(value, key){
          angular.forEach(value.Items, function(value, key) {
            if (value.Codebars == barcode) {
              return barcode;
            }
          });
        });
    });
  }
});

$scope.checkSerial = function(e) {
  if (e.which === 9) {
    // TODO: show progress indicator
    serialChecker
      .check($scope.itemsData, $scope.serial, e)
      .then(function(res) {
        // TODO: here you can use result
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // TODO: process error 
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // TODO: hide progress indicator 
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! This works! Do you maybe have some extra reading material on the whole "promise chain"?

Comment: Np, glad that my answer helped you. You can read [official angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or [this](http://jabberwocky.eu/2013/02/15/promises-in-javascript-with-q/) and [this](http://joseoncode.com/2013/05/23/promises-a-plus/). Or just use google for search, there is a lot of articles about promises.